# Hibernate inheritance insert child after parent

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a Hibernate, spring and GWT application. I have two tables: Employee and user.

Every user is an employee and thus I have One To One relation in the database( they are joined by the primary keys) and thus User extends Employee. Things work fine when I insert user first, it auto inserts parents correctly. However, the problem is when I try to add the user entry for an existing employee, which instead of inserting the user record with the parent Id, it re-creates the employee record and user record.

```
 @javax.persistence.Entity
 @javax.persistence.Table(name = "User")
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Id")
 public class User extends Employee
 { .... }

 @Reflectable(assignableClasses = true, superClasses = true)
 @javax.persistence.Entity
 @javax.persistence.Table(name = "Employee")
 @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Id")
 public class Employee
 { 
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      @Column(name="Id")
      public Integer getId()
      {
        return id;
      }
 }
```

Is this the right way to do things? How can I overcome this?

Thank you very much.

---

Update 1:

By Add user to it, I mean that I want to create a user with the same Id as employee.
which should basically become:

```
    Insert into User (Id, username,..) Values (1, "Username", ...)
```

Comment: Adding snipet of your existing code (eg. Entity declaration, Join annotation, etc) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the existing mapping makes any sense.

I would suggest scrapping the inheritance and mapping a one-to-one (or one-to-many) relationship between Employee and say UserAccount.

I think that better reflects your model.

An employee may or not be a user of a system. Employees who are have a user account on that system.

If more systems amy be added in future then use a one-to-many. Employees have user accounts on zero, one or more systems.

Comment: That is what I have done.. .  although I still believe that this is primarily a limitation due to the difference between the relational and oop paradigms... thanks

Comment: Obviously inheritance should only be used when the parent is never used separately

Answer (score 0):

Something doesn't sit right the first time I read your description and confirmed by your code snipet.

A few things you mentioned I break down into points:

- Every user is an employee
- I have OneToOne relation
- User extends Employee
- when I try to add the user entry for an existing employee

Just doesn't make sense.

Every User is an Employee and `User extends Employee` makes sense (somewhat)
but then why did you mention a One-to-One relation? There's no relation here, as also shown through your code.

A `User` is an `Employee`, but User does not own an Employee nor does an Employee own an User attribute (which is what "relationship" means).

Relationship is for example: an Employee has an Address, or a User has PermissionList.

And in the last point, when you said "*add the user entry for an existing employee*" shows that a `User` in this case supposed to be an attribute of an `Employee` and probably a `List` and not one-to-one (since you want to "add" to it).

Although if you step back, it doesnt make a lot of sense either because `Employee` does not own a `User` in the English sense.

A subclass / superclass is usually to describe a specific type of a more abstract type. eg. `Dog` is a subclass of an `Animal` because Dog is a specific type of Animal. Which I don't think what you want here.

I think you need to re think your design, and may be describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, no. A company has a list of employees, that may be a user 0f the company's system too. A user IS an employee. a user is a specific type of the more abstract type which is an employee that doesn't use the system. Your post is not correct. And it doesn't really have anything to do with the problem. I will update to clarify what is "add". Thanks for your effort.

Comment: By "OneToOne" I mean a database 1 to 1 relation. By joining the primary keys.